# Can a kaffir who was oppressed by others his whole life go to Jannah?

Tags: non-muslim, day-of-judgement

We are taught in Islam that on the Day of Judgement, people will flee from their parents, children, spouse etc. because those loved ones or others will complain to Allah swt that they did them wrong or withheld their rights and so therefore will try to take that person's good deeds from them to save themselves and if this individual has no more good deeds left to give, those they oppressed or did wrong to, will give that person their bad deeds, ultimately sending this "righteous" person to Hell who spent their whole life doing good deeds because of the number of people they harmed.

Now in the case of a kaffir, who may have a lot of bad deeds on Judgement Day because of never having made tawbah, will that person who faced oppression their whole life then be able to give their bad deeds to other kuffar who oppressed them, because the good deeds of the kuffar are null and void on that Day?
Therefore because this oppressed kaffir has given all their bad deeds to the other kuffar that have oppressed them, will they then somehow be able to enter Jannah?
Even at the lowest point?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 2):

[Verse (2:161)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(2:161:1))

> Indeed, those who disbelieve and die while they are disbelievers -
>   upon them will be the curse of Allah and of the angels and the people,
>   all together

[Verse (47:34)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(47:34:1))

> Indeed, those who disbelieved and averted [people] from the path of
>   Allah and then died while they were disbelievers - **never will Allah
>   forgive them**.

[Verse (24:39)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(24:39:1))

> But those who disbelieved - their deeds are like a mirage in a lowland
>   which a thirsty one thinks is water until, when he comes to it, he
>   finds it is nothing but finds Allah before Him, and He will pay him in
>   full his due; and Allah is swift in account.

[Sahih al-Bukhari, Narrated `Abdullah bin Al-Harith bin Naufal:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/232)

> Abbas bin Abdul Muttalib said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Did you
>   benefit Abu Talib with anything as he used to protect and take care of
>   you, and used to become angry for you?" The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Yes, he
>   is in a shallow place of Fire. But for me he would have been in the
>   lowest part of the Fire."

Who can do anything better the Abu Talib, he protected his entire life to Prophet (ﷺ).

So good deeds will only reduce the punishment but there is no way to enter into Jannah for any disbeliever.